# Loading a custom dataset from json annotations files for Keras classification task

Tags: python, json, keras

I am new to deep learning and would like to implement a simple classification task using Keras. My dataset contains over 2000 images & for each image I have a respective json file which contains the label for that image. Following is the code to load the json files & create the X (image) & Y (labels) arrays:

```
X = []
Y = []
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    # Get a list of files to process
    str = jsonpath + '/*.json'
    #print(str)
    json_files = glob.glob(str)
    for jsonfile,y in zip(json_files, executor.map(create_array, json_files)):
        X.append(y[0])
        Y.append(y[1])
```

where the function create_array is defined as follows:

```
def create_array(jsonfile):
    array_list = []
    y_list = []
    with open(jsonfile) as f:
            data = json.load(f)
            name = data['annotation']['data_filename']
            img = cv2.imread(imgDIR + '/' + name) 
            array_list.append(img)      
            l = data['annotation']['data_annotation']['classification'][0]['classification_label']
            y_list.append(l)
return array_list, y_list
```

It works for small no of images say 15, but for the entire set of 2000 images, the program gets automatically killed or sometimes it gives the error "MemoryError: out of memory".
Is there an efficient way to do this? How can I speed up this data pre-processing part to give it as an input to the keras classification model?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your images are pretty much ready for training and your preprocessing is simply about loading the files. json format might not be the fastest approach when it comes to loading data. If you're using somthing like pickle to save and load your images, you might experience a speed boost.

The other question is how to efficiently passing the data to keras. Normally you would use `model.fit` but since not all your data can fit into your memory you can use `model.fit_generator`
Ther keras [doc](https://keras.io/models/model/) gives us the folowing hint:

> The generator is run in parallel to the model, for efficiency. For
>   instance, this allows you to do real-time data augmentation on images
>   on CPU in parallel to training your model on GPU.
>
> The use of keras.utils.Sequence guarantees the ordering and guarantees
>   the single use of every input per epoch when using
>   use_multiprocessing=True.

[Here](https://keras.io/utils/#sequence) is an example how to implement such a generator.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The problem is creating the X-array which contains the images and I have to load individually each image into X-array using using json files, which I am presumming is costing me the most of my memory. But I have no choice but to decode the image label from individual json files and can't make use of the flow_from_directory function from keras while loading the dataset. Even though I am making use of ProcessPoolExecutor on a 6-core machine, I am running out of memory for 2055 images. Is there any work-around for this?

Comment: If you're running out of memory the number of PoolExecutor is not relevant. It just means that your images are too big for beeing laoded at the same time. As you stated flow_from_directory might be the best solution. Why don't you load your images one by one and save them in a new compatible format for flow_from_directory?

Comment: Ok, can you mention any compatible format for flow_from_directory that I can make use of? I am really lost here. Also, I was wondering if my image size is too big to be loaded simultaneously, then how does Keras flow_from_directory handle it elegantly?

Comment: https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/ I think the keras docu explain it well basically every typical image format is supported. Keras will load them just in time. So for every training step the images are loaded individually and then immidiately discarded after the step. So you will only have as many images as your batch_size in memory. Keras will execute this in parrallel so that your model does not have to wait too long for the images.